# Break statement in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, while-loop, primes, break

For a certain number `n` I have to find the next greater number than `n` which is prime. 
I had to solve this problem in Matlab. 
Below is my code:

**Solution1**

```
 function k = next_prime(n)
while n<10000000000
    n=n+1;
    if isprime(n)==true      
        k=n;
        break
    end
end
end
```

In this way the problem is correctly solved, but my initial solution was:

**Solution2**

```
function k = next_prime(n)
    while n<10000000000
        n=n+1;
        if isprime(n)==true      
            k=n;
        end
    break
    end
    end
```

The only difference between **Solution1** vs **Solution2** is the `break` statement place. 
Why **Solution1** is ok and **Solution2** is not ok?

Comment: Protip: you can still improve this a lot. A simple way to use half of the computational time: you are doung `n=n+1`, but even numbers can not be prime, so if you start from an odd number, you can do `n=n+2`.

Comment: You can also use `while n<1e8 & ~isprime(n)`. This more-or-less puts the `break` condition on `n` being prime directly in the loop condition.

Comment: Yet another tip: comparing to `true` never changes the value, so is always redundant. `isprime(n)==true` is exactly the same as `isprime(n)`. I think the latter is better readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`break`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/break.html) statement in MATLAB

> terminates the execution of a for or while loop. Statements in the loop after the break statement do not execute.

In solution 2 you are guaranteed to break at every loop iteration, not only if it is prime. Thus it will always only run the loop once, set n to n+1 and then break without setting k (unless coincidentally n+1 was prime).

It might help you to see it if you fix your indentation:

```matlab
function k = next_prime(n)
    while n<10000000000

        n=n+1;

        if isprime(n)==true      
            k=n;
        end

        break

    end
end
```

so the loop does 3 things, it increments `n`, it checks if `n` is prime and then it exits, always.

In solution 1, you only exit *if* `n` is prime, which is obviously what you want.